# Custom UITableViewCell doesn't update its subviews immediately, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with, among other things, a label and an imageView.  If the table view is the visible view and it has a cell on it, if I programmatically update the label's text and the imageView's image and log when I do it, it takes about 4 seconds AFTER I see the notification in the logs for the label and image to update.  Here is the order of what happens and how:

-Load the view containing the table and one custom cell

-Write a file to disk using and NSOperation (and queue)

-When the NSOperation is finished writing the file it fires a NSNotification (defaultCenter) which tells the cell's view to update the label and image **AND I set [self setNeedsDisplay]**

-Here I see in my logs that the cell has gotten the notification AND finished setting the new values

-~4 seconds later the cell's view actually updates.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to my particular problem hinged on the way in which I'm updating the data, I'm using an NSOperation (and queue) to send a notification, the notification responder then updates the view.  Problem is an NSOperation technically lives on another thread so what I should have done is this:

-Write a file to disk using and NSOperation (and queue)

-When the NSOperation is finished writing the file it fires a NSNotification (defaultCenter), **the responder should then performSelectorOnMainThread a method that does the actual updating of the view**

Did this and my cell updates right away.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem too. I have otherwise been aware of threading issues, but it didn't cross my mind in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) to update a particular cell in the table view.

Comment: That function would work but its a heavy handed solution since modifying the view should cause it to update, reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation: actually asks it to reload the cell.  The solution involved the NSOperation queue I mentioned, answer below.

Comment: @shizam: Thanks for explaining.  I'm still learning how the threading and event loops interact in iOS.  It ought to be documented somewhere.

Comment: Certainly, yea I went back and reread their sample NSOperationSample.xcodeproj project again to step through how they suggest using it and saw them using performSelectorOnMainThread.